# ILASM.exe process gets stuck during build

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, ilasm

I'm building a WPF library in Visual Studio 2015, and build never completes. In build output diagnostic level I can see the last task launched by msbuild is

```
calling 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ILAsm.exe' with /nologo "/out:[PathtoOutputDLL]" "[PathtoILfile]" /DLL "/resource=[PathtoResfile]"  /debug   (TaskId:65)
```

I can see the ilasm process is hanging around, not crashed, but nothing happens. If I forcefully stop the build by killing the msbuild and launch the same command in a console, it works, fast, outputs `Operation completed successfully`

I've used Process Monitor to get a handle on what's happening, and I found something weird-ish, when ilasm is successful (run from console), the process is named `ilasm.exe` and when it's a failure it's named `ILAsm.exe` (notice the case change), I don't see why, especially that the path to the exe are the same? There is something in the Process event log that mentions prefetch of the binary to be run:

Success:
"IRP_MJ_READ","C:\Windows\Prefetch\ILASM.EXE-FD82B157.pf","SUCCESS","Offset: 0, Length: 82 642, Priority: Normal"

Failure:
"IRP_MJ_READ","C:\Windows\Prefetch\ILASM.EXE-FD82B157.pf","SUCCESS","Offset: 0, Length: 82 844, Priority: Normal"

Same file but different sizes all of a sudden ?

Comment: We've been having this kind of question all week, uninstall Avast.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't have avast on this laptop, though I do have an antivirus, I'll look if that's the cause. Thanks

Comment: Disabled the antivirus, still a problem. Another hypothesis I'm testing/confirming: When removing some portions of the code, it's compiling. But it's very weird: If I remove method A it compiles, but it's not the whole story. If I leave method A in place and work on another class or another method, and there again if I remove method B, with method A still there; it ALSO compiles... I'm getting crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why it's stuck, but I've narrowed it down to bad relationship between a third party COM interop and UnmanagedExports by Robert Giesecke.

That particular class library was dependent on a third party COM interop, and its presence in the IL modified by UnmanagedExports  tripped somehow ILASM or UnmanagedExports in ways I don't know.
But one thing that unlocked the build is setting "Embed Interop types" to false, so that the COM interop does not end up in the output, then UnmanagedExports works without issues.