# Cannot build .NET project with some MS-Excel interop related members

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I'm having troubles with the Excel Interop library, used to automate Excel from a C# dll (.NET Framework 4.8).

For many properties exposed by Introp.Excel, Visual Studio 2022 hangs on build and it is not possible to compile.

Project is using [DLLExport](https://github.com/3F/DllExport) to export some static methods to unmanaged consumers.

This code compiles :

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public static string TestExcelCompile()
{
    Application ExcelApp = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

    Workbooks xlWorkbooks = ExcelApp.Workbooks;

    return "";
}
```

When I try to compile this code, the build hangs immediatly without any information :

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public static string TestExcelCompile()
{
    Application ExcelApp = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

    Workbooks xlWorkbooks = ExcelApp.Workbooks;
    
    int WbCount = xlWorkbooks.Count; // This is the difference.

    return "";
}
```

Do you know why the build hangs when trying to use some properties ?

Comment: Builds don't hang, they fail with compilation errors. Execution hangs. What is the actual problem and *actual* error? What does the `Errors` window show in Visual Studio?

Comment: When trying to build, the output displays "Build started: [Name of assembly]" and it hangs endlessly. I can wait a week, no error will be displayed, even if I configure the build to be max verbose.

Comment: I can compile and run your exact code in LinqPad. It only requires that Excel is already open. There must be something wrong with your setup.

Comment: I just succeed to have more verbose build output and the build seems to hang by the stuff done by DllExport (to export some static method to unmanaged code).

Comment: DllExport has nothing to do with COM Interop. It's what *your* application exposes to C/C++ applications. You haven't posted any code related to DllExport either

Comment: The code compile when I remove the DllExport stuff. It seems to be a DllExport bug ... The build was hanging, whenn DllExport calls ilasm.exe after its modifications. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found an explaination and a workaround here:

[ILASM.exe process gets stuck during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784556/ilasm-exe-process-gets-stuck-during-build)

"DllExport" has troubles when the excel interop reference option "Embed Interop types" is set to true.

I tryed to set it to false, and now everything works fine.